# how to get <head> content of the current page with jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, head

how to get `<head>` content of the current page

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could use the javascript DOM API like this:

```
var headContent = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Just use `document.head.innerHTML`. [Can I use?](http://caniuse.com/#search=document.head)

Comment: @AlexandruEftimie while `document.head` is probably preferred in most modern browsers. It won't work in Internet Explorer 8 or earlier

Answer (score 13):

You can use an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) to get `<head>`, for example:

```
$("head")
//for example:
alert($("head").html()); //alerts the <head> children
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/EqR6p/)

Answer (score 6):

Simply as:

```
document.head
```

which returns an object DOM Object.

```
document.head.innerHTML
```

which returns text, like: '<title>Title of the page...'.

Comment: Check browser compatibility for `document.head`. I believe it's not supported in IE till v9.

Comment: Yes. It's supported from IE9 
[developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/head](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/head)